# b.module(...).info is not a function and Module 'angular-ladda' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this error

> b.module(...).info is not a function
>   [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
>   [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-ladda due
>   to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-ladda' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

i have put angular-ladda to angular module :

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [
      'angular-ladda',
  'angular-jwt',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngAria',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngMessages',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngStorage',
  'ui.router',
  'permission',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ui.utils',
  'ui.validate',
  'toaster',
  'ui.select',
  'oc.lazyLoad',
  'restangular',
  'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination',
  'pharmaDbApp.filters',
  'angularMoment',
  'angularFileUpload',
  'ngFileUpload',
  'daterangepicker',
  'ngProgress'
    ]);
```

And also put all script in index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>MyAPP</title>
  <meta name="description" content="MyAPP"/>
  <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
  <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ladda/dist/ladda.min.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/select2/select2.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/select2-bootstrap-css/select2-bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angularjs-toaster/toaster.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-3-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ngprogress/ngProgress.css">

  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css(app) styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/font.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom.css" type="text/css"/>
  <!-- endbuild -->

</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm">
<div id="app" class="app ng-scope app-header-fixed app-aside-fixed" ui-view></div>
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- Moment -->
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
<!-- Angular -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-validate/dist/validate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ladda/js/spin.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ladda/js/ladda.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ladda/dist/angular-ladda.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angularUtils-pagination/dirPagination.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angularjs-toaster/toaster.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<!-- lazyload -->
<script src="bower_components/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-daterangepicker/js/angular-daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- datetimepicker -->
<script src="bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script> -->

<script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/js-xlsx/dist/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/js-xlsx/dist/xlsx.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/alasql/dist/alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngprogress/build/ngprogress.min.js"></script>


<!-- Script is used for supporting file uploading in ie9 -->  
<script type="text/javascript">
    FileAPI = {
      debug: true,
      //forceLoad: true, html5: false, //to debug flash in HTML5 browsers
     // wrapInsideDiv: true, //experimental for fixing css issues
      //only one of jsPath or jsUrl.
      jsPath: 'bower_components/ng-file-upload/',
      jsUrl: 'bower_components/ng-file-upload/FileAPI.min.js',

      //only one of staticPath or flashUrl.
      staticPath: 'bower_components/ng-file-upload/',

      flashUrl: 'bower_components/ng-file-upload/FileAPI.flash.swf'

    };
  </script>
  <script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>

<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<!-- App -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/config.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/router.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/constants.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/filters.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/userInfo.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/authenticationService.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/session.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/tokenInterceptor.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/datetime.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/notification.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/ui-select-required.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/ui-butterbar.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/ui-nav.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/ui-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/ui-sortable.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/permission.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/datetimePicker.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/string_to_num.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>

<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- Lazy loading -->
</body>

</html>
```

This is my button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" 
                    ladda="login.processing" 
                    data-style="slide-right" 
                    ng-disabled='form.$invalid'>Log in</button>
```

bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
"angular": "~1.3.15",
"angular-animate": "~1",
"angular-aria": "~1",
"angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.0",
"angular-bootstrap-nav-tree": "*",
"angular-cookies": "~1",
"angular-file-upload": "~1.1.6",
"angular-material": "~0.10.0",
"angular-messages": "~1",
"angular-resource": "~1",
"angular-sanitize": "~1",
"angular-touch": "~1",
"angular-ui-calendar": "latest",
"angular-ui-grid": "~3.0.0-rc.16",
"angular-ui-router": "0.2.15",
"angular-ui-select": "0.14.3",
"angular-ui-utils": "~0.2.1",
"angular-xeditable": "~0.1.8",
"angularjs-toaster": "~0.4.8",
"animate.css": "~3.2.0",
"bootstrap": "~3.3.0",
"bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^2.1.22",
"bootstrap-3-datepicker": "latest",
"bootstrap-filestyle": "~1.1.2",
"bootstrap-rtl": "~3.3.4",
"bootstrap-slider": "*",
"datatables": "~1.10.4",
"flot": "~0.8.3",
"flot-spline": "*",
"flot.orderbars": "*",
"flot.tooltip": "~0.8.4",
"font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
"footable": "~2.0.3",
"fullcalendar": "~2.2.6",
"html5sortable": "*",
"jquery": "~2.1.3",
"jquery.easy-pie-chart": "~2.1.6",
"jquery.sparkline": "~2.1.2",
"jquery_appear": "~0.3.3",
"moment": "^2.6.0",
"ngImgCrop": "~0.2.0",
"ngstorage": "~0.3.0",
"oclazyload": "~0.5.1",
"screenfull": "~1.2.1",
"simple-line-icons": "~0.1.1",
"slimscroll": "~1.3.3",
"textAngular": "~1.2.2",
"venturocket-angular-slider": "~0.3.2",
"waves": "~0.7.2",
"angular-ladda": "^0.3.4",
"restangular": "~1.5.2",
"angularUtils-pagination": "angular-utils-pagination#^0.11.0",
"select2-bootstrap-css": "select2-bootstrap3-css#^1.4.6",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.2",
"braintree-web": "^2.22.2",
"angular-jwt": "^0.0.9",
"eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.44",
"filesaver": "*",
"creditcard.js": "^2.0.3",
"angular-ui-validate": "^1.2.2",
"angular-moment": "^0.10.3",
"ng-file-upload-shim": "^12.0.4",
"ng-file-upload": "^12.0.4",
"angular-daterangepicker": "^0.2.2",
"alasql": "^0.2.7",
"xlsx": "*",
"ngprogress": "^1.1.3"
```

package.json

```
"autoprefixer-core": "^5.2.1",
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.7",
"grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
"grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
"grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
"grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
"grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.0",
"grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
"grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
"grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
"grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
"grunt-jscs": "^1.8.0",
"grunt-karma": "*",
"grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
"grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.9.2",
"grunt-postcss": "^0.5.5",
"grunt-recess": "^1.0.0",
"grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
"grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
"grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
"jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
"jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "*",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "*",
"time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
```

Comment: can you add all the references?

Comment: what kind of references do you need? @Sajeetharan

Comment: whatever you have in index.html

Comment: @Misti tehre is something wrong with the references you adding. Share you all eferences you adding .

Comment: @Sajeetharan check it

Comment: @Ved check it bro

Comment: @Misti I don't see any mistake in your code.

Comment: @Ved actually i have run this and it works, but after several update by other devs it is not working. Then, i decided to replace vendor.js with my last work vendor.js.
i am just curios.

Comment: @Misti It is not a solution. If error, there msut be something wrong. Either with version or references